# Customize Laravel paginate count query

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagination

I've a Laravel paginate query as such -

```
$query = static::newQuery();
$query->join('users AS u', 'comments.created_by', '=', 'u.id');
$query->leftJoin('users AS u1', 'comments.updated_by', '=', 'u1.id');
$query->leftJoin('images AS i', 'i.id', '=', 'u.image_id');
$query->selectRaw('comments.id, text, html, comments.created_by, comments.updated_by, comments.created_at, comments.updated_at, '
        . 'u.name AS created_by_name, u1.name AS updated_by_name, '
        . '(SELECT count(c.id) FROM bookstack.comments c WHERE c.parent_id = comments.id AND page_id = ?) AS cnt_sub_comments, i.url AS avatar ', 
        [$pageId]);

if (empty($commentId)) {
    $query->whereRaw('page_id = ? AND parent_id IS NULL', [$pageId]);
} else {
    $query->whereRaw('page_id = ? AND parent_id = ?', [$pageId, $commentId]);
}        
$query->orderBy('created_at');
return $query;
```

I'm then running a paginate on the query object.

```
$query->paginate($count);
```

This results in the following query being run -

```
select comments.id, text, html, comments.created_by, comments.updated_by, comments.created_at, comments.updated_at, u.name AS created_by_name, 
u1.name AS updated_by_name, (SELECT count(c.id) FROM bookstack.comments c WHERE c.parent_id = comments.id AND page_id = '2') AS cnt_sub_comments, 
i.url AS avatar  from `comments` inner join `users` as `u` on `comments`.`created_by` = `u`.`id` 
left join `users` as `u1` on `comments`.`updated_by` = `u1`.`id` 
left join `images` as `i` on `i`.`id` = `u`.`image_id` 
where page_id = '2' AND parent_id = '2' order by `created_at` asc limit 20 offset 0
```

In addition the following count query runs,

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` inner join `users` as `u` on `comments`.`created_by` = `u`.`id` 
left join `users` as `u1` on `comments`.`updated_by` = `u1`.`id` 
left join `images` as `i` on `i`.`id` = `u`.`image_id` 
where page_id = '2' AND parent_id = '2'
```

Would it be possible to have the count query not do a unnecessary JOIN here?

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand how paginate work. Since your query need join to other table, and added with complex select (ex:include with function like month on the select argument). The query itself must join with subquery (as mention above)..

the right answer for this problem will be turn your query above into view table. And treat the view as table on model. When you run, you will type less coding than your code today. And with this view, you will make less error/warning during development.

As I mention earlier using view, you can't make this only 1 view. Create view from this query

```
SELECT count(c.id) FROM bookstack.comments c WHERE c.parent_id = comments.id AND page_id = '2'
```

then used it on user_comment (view). This is not easy answer, but this method can make your code readable.